# Angularjs Facebook Login: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, restangular, ngroute

I am using angular-facebook module for adding Facebook Login capability to my application.

Generally I get the following error while loading the page:

`The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

When I get this error the facebook login popup comes empty/blank or unable to login.

My angular module dependencies are below:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'facebook', 'restangular', 'LocalStorageModule'])
```

My index.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ..
    ..
     <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Somewhere in the code the will be reference like <someObject>.appendChild. While this line is executing, <someObject> will be null. You will have to see why it is coming as null or assign some value to it.

Comment: can you show the js snippet?

Comment: @Shikhar I'm using angular-facebook (https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook/blob/master/lib/angular-facebook.js) as a module and it initializes Facebook sdk at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of `ng-view` tag in `<body>`
ngRoute organizes the content of body itself but facebook js sdk tries to control 'fb-root' div under body.

The solution is to move ng-view to an inner div under body and create a fb-root div optionally:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```