# How can I implement the Plaid API using Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, plaid

I was able to successfully implement the API on web, here is what it looks like, I have a button in a regular html file...

```
<div>
    <span class="radio-button radio-left" id="sandboxLinkButton">Sandbox Mode</span>
</div>
```

I include the script tag...

```
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
```

and I include the following javascript in the html body...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sandboxHandler = Plaid.create({
      clientName: 'SUM',
      env: 'tartan',
      product: 'auth',
      key: 'test_key',
      onSuccess: function(token) {
        //window.location = '/accounts.html?public_token=' + token;
        console.log("yes");
      },
    });

  // Open the "Institution Select" view using the sandbox Link handler.
    document.getElementById('sandboxLinkButton').onclick = function() {
      sandboxHandler.open();
    };

</script>
```

Now I want to do the same using angular js. I'm using an ionic framework (not that it really matters). So I first display the necessary html using the following...

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
});
```

My `menu.html` file contains the following button...

```
 <span ng-click="create()" class="radio-button radio-left" id="sandboxLinkButton">Sandbox Mode</span>
```

on `ng-click` it reaches the following controller. I tried to implement the API in this controller to no avail...

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
    var sandboxHandler = Plaid.create({
    clientName: 'SUM',
    env: 'tartan',
    product: 'auth',
    key: 'test_key',
    onSuccess: function(token) {
        console.log("yes");
    },
  });

  $scope.create = function() {
    sandboxHandler.open();
  }
});
```

I get the error `Plaid` is not defined in the controller. Why is that?

**EDIT**

I replicated a web app version using angular and it worked. I used the following CDN instead of the ionic/angular one

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But I still can't get it to work on my ionic web app. Has anyone else ever come across this issue?

Comment: Are you still including the `link-initialize.js` from the Plaid CDN?

Comment: @Phil its included in my html file, so yeah, I think so

Comment: Which HTML file though? I don't think it will work in your `menu.html` file if that's where it is

Comment: @Phil right. I placed it inside my `index.html`. The file to which `menu.html` content is appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I included the library I immediately got the following error in the browser: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

There are similar questions about this error regarding different libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575237/cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null-with-disqus-on-backbone-website) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404996/angularjs-facebook-login-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null), however I was not able to solve the problem based on those answers.

The closest thing to a solution that I found was in [this issue report](https://github.com/plaid/link/issues/67) within the Plaid repository on GitHub. It describes a problem with the library not working when placed in the `<head>` tag. A [commit](https://github.com/plaid/link/commit/22959e98ecbdac01f2a2e0519042362002d80ae1) within this issue report describes that this problem can be solved by including the script inside the `<body>` tag instead of the `<head>` tag.

I would recommend subscribing to the issue report to see whether other solutions will be introduced in the future.

**So tldr; Try moving the `<script>` tag from `<head>` to the `<body>`.**

Comment: yes I get that error too, I'll check out those links and see what I can find out.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>` from the `<head>` to `<body>` yet?

Comment: Yeah I did, still get the same errors and the API won't work. I'm not sure what to do. Would it be helpful if I make a simple public repo on github with my issue?

Comment: That's really odd, it immediately worked when I tried it. Please do create the repository as I will be able to test your code on my machine and help you out that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Plain angular wrapper that I created:

https://github.com/khashayar/ng-plaid